# REGEX for Address to not allow mult space, but allow 0-9A-Za-z

Tags: regex

I have the following regex

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9.]+\\s)*[a-zA-Z0-9.]+$
```

This is working fine... however the issue is when I add a space I get invalid... i only want invalid when there is mult spaces.

For example; this is what I am looking for:

- `123 Main street` (without space after 't' is fine)
- `123 Main street`  (with space after 't' is NOT fine) [but it should be ok]
- `123 Main street`   (with more than 1 space after 't' should fail)

I tried this regex for mult spaces after the last char, and thats fine... but I want to limit to 0-9,A-Za-z

```
(?<!\.|\s)\s{2,}
```

However, putting them together has been a problem for me... how can I handle?

Comment: Are you sure the backslash number is fine?

Comment: on the first regex? yes, it works as expected in my use case. this is for a project for work, so its slightly different how it looks at the regex

Comment: Your regex works fine, doesn't it? See https://regex101.com/r/pHm5dO/1 If you want to allow a single trailing space, just add `\s?` before `$` - see https://regex101.com/r/pHm5dO/2

Comment: If you want to allow a single trailing space, just add `\s?` before `$` - see https://regex101.com/r/pHm5dO/2

Comment: Is this matching a whole string, or searching for the address in running text? If searching, the `$` anchor won't work, but a `\b` word boundary would.

Comment: thanks Wiktor. that works for me. appreciate it...